# Android TV move focus between RecyclerViews

Tags: focus, android-recyclerview, android-tv, d-pad

I am building an Android TV app with the following layout:
[image]

Both lists on the left and on the right are RecyclerViews with vertical LinearLayoutManagers, Header view is static. Navigation with D-PAD works fine within one list, but when switching from one list to another there are issues. Focus moves from, say list1's item 5 to list2' item 5. When list 2 is short has less than 5 items, it just loses focus.

I want the last focused item index saved and when the user navigates list1-list2-list1 the item with that index to gain focus again and also prevent the views from losing focus. Is there any good solution to this?

Required behaviour:
user navigates to the top of the list and presses "UP" - focus stays where it was, nothing happens.
user navigates to the bottom of the list and presses "DOWN" - focus stays where it was, nothing happens.
user navigates from list1 to list2 - the item, that previously had focus in list2, gains focus or item0 gains focus if none was focused previously.

main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="false"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_poster"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/episodes_list_item_height"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/episodes_list_image_width"
                    />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        />

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_release_date"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="left"
                            />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_rating"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"
                            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_star_white_24dp"
                            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/view_padding_small"
                            />

                    </FrameLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_description"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_seasons_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="false"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_episodes_list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:focusable="false"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

item layout, used for both lists:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/seasons_list_item_height"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:focusable="true"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_episodes_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:ems="10"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: could you post your xml files ?

Comment: so you want to move focus between both of your recycler view right could you explain bit more ?

Comment: right. i want to remember last focused position in recyclerviews. and when the user navigates from list1 to list2 and back to list1 i want to restore previously focused item of list1. the same goes for list2. also i want the focus not to move when the user presses 'up' on d-pad when item1 in list1 is focused and so on

Comment: have u tried any code to get focus for last position if not then check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682277/how-do-i-get-the-position-selected-in-a-recyclerview

Comment: jaydroider, selection and focus are different things. i can get the last focused position, but can't see a way to restore it.

Comment: you mean when you r navigating with remote then u facing this problem ?

Comment: exactly that. i'm using the standard nexus player remote (a d-pad)

Comment: could you please add more details to your suggestion? what exactly should i try?

Comment: Have you tried making them siblings? I have something similar to what you are doing and it works fine for me as long as they are in the same relative layout. I know it makes it a pain to style but at least things will stay in focus.

Comment: check out my answer to see a better way to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Digging through Google's Leanback library sources answered my payers.
If you face the same trouble, just wrap your RecyclerViews with [this](https://github.com/wuakitv/leanback-v17/blob/master/src/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/PersistentFocusWrapper.java) and don't forget to set

```
private boolean mPersistFocusVertical = false;
```

if you want the focus to be persisted when searching horizontally, like in my layout.

Comment: How did you use this private class? Can you give an example code on the solution, do you mean wrapping it in the xml?

Comment: just copy the code. it has no dependencies with private access. it works for me.

Comment: Link doesn't works (404). Could you please to provide correct link?

Comment: it's PersistentFocusWrapper class from Google's v17-leanback library. You can search for the latest version. Now it's available here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v17/leanback/src/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/PersistentFocusWrapper.java

Comment: @ЄвгенГарастович Did you get any crashes with it? I get it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39856750/how-to-implement-scrolling-in-recyclerview-on-android-tv

Answer (score 0):

Modify your main layout as below.

For directional navigation we can add properties like nextFocusDown, nextFocusLeft, nextFocusRight, nextFocusUp to focus relevant items as per our requirements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_poster"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/episodes_list_item_height"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/episodes_list_image_width"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_release_date"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_rating"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_star_white_24dp"
                        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/view_padding_small"
                        />

                </FrameLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_seasons_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/rv_episodes_list"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_episodes_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:nextFocusUp="@+id/rv_seasons_list"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will solve your problem !!

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but this doesn't help. I need the focus to stay were it is when it reaches the top/bottom of the list. And it didn't affect moving focus left/right at all.

Comment: put screen shot of your app with relevant rows you have.

Comment: i've used your code to create a little test project here https://jgarin@bitbucket.org/jgarin/tv-test.git when you press and hold d-pad's up/down focus moves from one list to another and previously focused position is not saved/restored

Comment: try to get last focus position of list 1 and store in share preferences.

Comment: getting and storing is not a problem, i can handle that. but restoring focus is. any ideas on that?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27194044/how-to-properly-highlight-selected-item-on-recyclerview check this

Answer (score 0):

To make my lists remember focused position, I used **VerticalGridView** from leanback library *instead* of **RecyclerView.** and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).