# How to get getFirstVisiblePosition() and getChildAt(0) in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

How to get `getFirstVisiblePosition()` and `getChildAt(0)` in `recyclerview`? Because I want to get position when user click item.

and code in listview is

```
index = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View v = listview.getChildAt(0);
top = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - listview.getPaddingTop());
```

but I want to use recyclerview.

How to set it?

Answer (score 1):

Both are available via the LayoutManager:

```
layoutManager.findViewByPosition(position);
layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
```

Comment: sorry Where to set it

Comment: you need cast to special view and use addView

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `LinearLayoutManager` you can use:

`int findFirstVisibleItemPosition();`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `getAdapterPosition()` in you view holder. for example:

```
private class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

       public myViewHolder(View view) {
           super(view);
             view.setOnclickListener(this);
       }

 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {

       int clickedItemPosition = view.getAdapterPosition();

}
   }
```

[Android Recycler View Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)

[How do I get the position selected in a RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682277/how-do-i-get-the-position-selected-in-a-recyclerview)