# RecyclerView adapterPosition is deprecated and Gradle throwing error as Could not find accessor bindingAdapterPosition

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

In the latest Gradle plugin When I try to access the adapter position field IDE showing as deprecated. Suggesting to use getBindingAdapterPosition() instead of adapterPosition

But When I  try to access the field `getBindingAdapterPosition()` IDE is throwing error as

```
Could not find accessor com.rizek.android.users.adapters.recyclerview.cart.ProductListAdapter.ExpandViewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition
```

My XML File :

```
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:onClick="@{()->frequencyOptionInteractor.onRecurringOptionChanged(recurringViewHolder.adapterPosition,frequencyOption)}"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout12"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout12"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/frequency_option_selector"
        bind:stateActivated="@{frequencyOptionAdapter.selectedPosition==recurringViewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition}" />
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682277/how-do-i-get-the-position-selected-in-a-recyclerview
you should try this.

Comment: I tried both bindingAdapterPosition and  getAbsoluteAdapterPosition issue persists

Answer (score 5):

If you haven't done it yet, you can try to add RecyclerView manually to your

```
build.gradle
```

file (module) :

```
// RecyclerView
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0"
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ViewPager2 make sure to add it as dependency.

```
implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0"
```